# YAML with AWS secrets to POJO conversion

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, security, yaml, aws-secrets-manager

We have a service which reads its config from a Yaml file. We are planning to integrate with AWS secret manager to store secrets. A sample yaml is like,

`password: abcd`

after Secrets manager integration, the Yaml would look like,

`password: secret://secret-password`

The prefix `secret://` will indicate that its needs to be resolved.

We were currently looking jackson-yaml mapper to map yaml to POJO. 
I wanted to know that how can we plug the property resolution code in this library (or any other yaml-pojo library) which provides a hook in the deserialization process so that I can resolve the properties

Comment: Are you 100% sure you want to include calls to external services (or any kind of IO for that matter) in the config's serialization?

Comment: Is there any better alternative?